# Show that $\lim\limits_{x \to 2} \bigg( 2^{x} \bigg)=4$ using epsilon-delta

Tags: calculus, epsilon-delta

I have the following problem,

> **Show that $\lim\limits_{x \to 2} \bigg( 2^{x} \bigg)=4$ by finding a $\delta$ that guarantees that $2^{x}$ is within $\varepsilon$ of $4$
>   when $\varepsilon=0.01$**

I want to prove that by using the epsilon delta proof, so I start as follows:
\begin{align*}
\left| f(x) - L \right| &< \varepsilon\\
\left| 2^{x} -4 \right| &< \varepsilon\
\end{align*}

but then I find myself completely confused... and I am also confused about the bit "guarantees that $2^{x}$ is within $\varepsilon$ of $4$
 when $\varepsilon=0.01$", I am not sure what to do with $\varepsilon=0.01$.. I would really appreciate some help.. been stuck on this one for a while...

Comment: Do you know how epsilon delta proofs work

Comment: @DonThousand I was able to solve similar problems but only been stuck on this one, maybe I did not understand it as much as I thought I did

Comment: Because the "guarantees that $2^x$ is within $\varepsilon$ of $4$" is the standard process in epsilon-delta proofs. I could explain how to do this one, but I'm of the opinion that this should tell you that you need to study the methods a bit better.

Comment: @DonThousand I think my main problem is that I am not sure how to go from the first step, I think if I knew I would have been able to proceed

Comment: What do you mean by "first step"

Comment: @DonThousand I meant going from $\left| 2^{x} -4 \right| < \varepsilon $

Comment: Ok, here's a hint: Consider $\lim\limits_{x\to2^+}|2^x-4|$ first. So, $2^x-4>0$. So you can drop the absolute value.

Comment: Then, when doing $\lim\limits_{x\to2^-}$, you simply consider $4-2^x$.

Comment: @DonThousand Thank you, I think I got it by now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to prove the following. For any given $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that when $0<|x-2|<\delta,$ it follows that $|2^x-4|<\epsilon$.

Consider when $x>2$. Since $2^x$ is increasing, $|2^x-4|=2^x-4$ so solving $2^x-4<\epsilon$, this holds iff $2^x<\epsilon+4$ iff $x<\log_2(\epsilon+4)$ iff $x-2<\log_2(\epsilon+4)-2$. The right hand side is positive since $\log_2(\epsilon+4)>\log_2(4)=2$. The if and only ifs allow you to go backwards in the proof. Therefore, for the right limit, it seems appropriate to choose $\delta_1=\log_2(\epsilon+4)-2$.

Now consider when $x<2$. Then it becomes $4-2^x<\epsilon$ iff $4-\epsilon<2^x$ iff $\log_2(4-\epsilon)<x$ iff $-\log_2(4-\epsilon)>-x$ iff $2-\log_2(4-\epsilon)>2-x$ . Thus, for the leftward limit, it seems that  $\delta_2=2-\log_2(4-\epsilon)$ works.

For the combined limit, we want $0<|x-2|<\delta$. Choose $\delta=\min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$.